# winget not working unless I do

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-command-prompt

When I open Powershell, and type winget - this is the response:

> **winget** : The term 'winget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - winget
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (winget:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command winget was not found, but does
> exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
> commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
> command, instead type: ".\winget". See "get-help
> about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

But if I go to the folder where winget is located (in my case *%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\winget.exe* and type in winget with a "./" infront of it - it works fine! So my question is, how do I point a command like winget to execute the file located as mentioned above, but from any directory I'm in?

For instance, in linux I can use

"**alias** winget='%AppData%\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\winget.exe"

and it'll point the command to the location specified. Is there any way I can do this, but in Powershell/CMD?

Answer (score 1):

"if I go to the folder where winget is located ... a "./" infront of it "

instead, just put a "." in front of the whole path to winget.

i don't have winget, but this launches acrobat reader for me in powershell from any directory:

."C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

Comment: So you're saying I should open Powershell and type ".winget" or ".%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\winget.exe"?

Comment: the whole path to winget.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a fresh Windows 10 Pro 22H2 install. Used Microsoft Store to install the **App Installer** to get `winget` available in PowerShell, but got the same error message as op.

To get it working I had to use the **Repair** function in Settings --> Apps --> App Installer --> Advanced options --> Repair.